# How to Run NodeJS Project With Class By Not Using new Keyword

Tags: javascript, node.js, typescript

I am developing a NodeJS project by using TypeScript. But I can't figure out how to run `app.ts` file by using class.

How to run Root class without new keyword ? That is the point.

**App.TS**

```
// Express
import { application as app } from 'express';

// Controllers
import { UserController } from './controllers/user.controller'

export class App {
  constructor(userController: UserController) {
    console.log("App is running");
    console.log("UserController url path is : ", userController.getUrlPath);
  }

  run(): void {
    app.listen(3000, function () {
      console.log('App is running on port 3000!');
    });
  }
}
```

**Root.TS**

```
import { App } from "../app";

export class Root {
    constructor(application: App) {
        application.run();
    }
}
```

How to run Root class without new keyword ? That is the point.

Because it has to get instances of parameters of its constructor with dependency injection.

**Compiler start code :**

```
ts-node-dev --respawn --transpileOnly ./app/root.ts
```

This code tries to run root.ts file's code. There is a Root class but there is no created object of class. So, there is no runnable class or method.

Comment: What transpiler do you use ? tsc ? Webpack ?

Comment: dependency injection do not existe. Are you using Angular in front-end to do this confusion ?
Only Angular has this type of injection. You must do a `new UserController()`

Comment: @Gilsdav I am using TypeScript at NodeJS project. Dependency injection works. But my code is not fine to use dependency injection for now. Because I'm trying to create App class by using new keyword. It is completely wrong and I don't know correct way.

Comment: @Gilsdav I edited the codes. Please check.

Comment: DI doesn't exist as I know. Do you mean you use something like Inversify ?https://github.com/inversify/InversifyJS

Answer (score 0):

You cannot "execute" a .ts file with Node.JS, you need to compile it first in JavaScript.
Use the typescript module to do this: `npm i -s typescript`

Then run the command `tsc` in your terminal.

Comment: Compiler is running correctly. The problem is the code actually. tsc is used at this.

Answer (score 0):

To execute TS files you can simply install and use [`ts-node`](https://www.npmjs.com/package/ts-node), it has all the same behaviour as a normal node but will transpile any file needed.

This way you won't even need to transpile your code before running it.